# How to load my localhost java spring boot web app from an executable file

Tags: java, spring-boot, desktop-application

I have a spring boot web application in Java and which uses front end libraries/framework like Angular/React. Suppose my web app URL is http://localhost:8080/xyz. I need to create an executable file(platform independent) and when I click on it then it should open my web app in browser window and the application should start. Can someone tell how can I achieve this.

**EDIT :** **I just want something clickable on my desktop and upon clicking on it will run the application and then it will open the browser window which will load the web app url and user can hit/do rest of things as a normal web app.So the clickable icon should function as a desktop app but functionality is to run the java web app and open it in browser.**

Adding pom.xml here , which i used in my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>proman</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.upgrad.proman</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>proman-api</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.upgrad.proman</groupId>
            <artifactId>proman-service</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                        <language>spring</language>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                        <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                        <modelPackage>com.upgrad.proman.api.model</modelPackage>
                        <configOptions>
                            <java8>true</java8>
                            <sourceFolder>.</sourceFolder>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>

                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.18</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-generators</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-rc0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>signup</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/endpoints/signup.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>spring</language>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>useradmin</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/endpoints/useradmin.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>spring</language>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>authentication</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/endpoints/authentication.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>spring</language>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Build your spring-boot application then you can run the jar in any environment by executing "java -jar <application-name.jar>"

Comment: So , what you are saying is that if I execute "java -jar <application-name.jar>" then it will create an executable file. Also can you tell me whether I need to modify my pom.xml file for this to achieve.

Comment: I dont understand who and why downvoted this question.

Comment: "I need to create an executable file(platform independent)", this executable is the output jar :-)

Answer (score 4):

Make the app runnable:

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Update the starter class (be sure to check `headless(false)`):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DesktopBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // check for availability:
        if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            System.out.println("This app needs a desktop manager to run, exiting.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(DesktopBootApplication.class).headless(false).run(args);
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void openBrowserAfterStartup() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        // open default browser after start:
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://localhost:8080"));
    }
}
```

You might want to add a shutdown option to stop the server. I.e. using the [Actuator shutdown resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints), you can stop it from JavaScript in your page.

I used a tray icon here:

```
@Configuration
public class DesktopConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    // Add a tray icon to stop the app:
    @Bean
    public void openTrayIcon() throws Exception {
        TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/spring.png")).getImage());
        icon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        icon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Exiting app ...");
                SystemTray.getSystemTray().remove(icon);
                SpringApplication.exit(appContext);
            }
        });
        SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(icon);
        icon.displayMessage("Spring Boot", "Application started", MessageType.INFO);
    }
}
```

You need some kind of icon to get this to work. Save any png file (called `spring.png`) in `src/main/resources`.

Build the app running `mvnw`. It can be found in the `target` directory afterwards.

Comment: I modified my pom.xml(as given in the question) file to make app runnable as you mentioned and when I tried to build I got the error - "Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE:repackage failed:"

Comment: What follows repackage failed? Did you set `packaging` to `jar`?

Comment: I made it work to fix the error , thanks. But what I was expecting is - I should have one clickable icon in desktop and upon clicking on it will run the application and then only it should open the browser. Sorry I missed to mention one part in my actual question. I have edited it. So the clickable icon should function as a desktop app but functionality is to run tha java web app and open it in browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the command
 `java -jar "location-of-your-jar"`
in a batch file and click it.

The below can be saved as some-file.bat and will run in background on a click and you will have to kill it manually as per your requirements. If you want to stop application on close of the terminal, comment the lines with ("rem") and uncomment below lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem rem if JAVA is set and run from :startapp labeled section below, else the program exit through :end labeled section.
if not "[%JAVA_HOME%]"=="[]" goto start_app
echo. JAVA_HOME not set. Application will not run!
goto end


:start_app
echo. Using java in %JAVA_HOME%

rem run java application in background and you will have to manually kill the process to stop the app(not recommended).
start javaw -jar "/your/location/myapp.jar"

rem comment above line and uncomment below to run java application in foreground so that you can close the terminal and app will close (recommended).
rem java -jar "/your/location/myapp.jar"

echo. Your spring boot app is started...
goto end

:end
rem clean if files are created.
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pom file should be like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.example.sample</groupId>
   <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>demo</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

   <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       ...........
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Make sure that your project pom.xml has `parent` and `build` as above

Then run maven command

```
mvn package
```

to build jar file.

You can run jar file in any environment by executing below command

```
java -jar <filename.jar>
```

or

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

from your root path of your project

Comment: I had edited my question to add this - "EDIT : I just want something clickable on my desktop and upon clicking on it will open the browser window which will load the web app url and user can hit/do rest of things as a normal web app." . I am expecting this.

Comment: @user3742125, check if my answer is what you are looking for. Let me know if how it works for you..

Answer (score 0):

Another option is configure your application to start as service [1][2].

The install program will:

1. Copy app files
2. Create service
3. Start service
4. Create a desktop icon pointing to app's url

   [1] https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-as-a-windows-service-in-5-minutes

   [2] https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html